# banning search engine through robots txt file

Tags: search-engine, robots.txt

I want to make sure my robots.txt file is set up properly to disallow one specific search engine from indexing the site:

```
User-agent: msnbot-media
Disallow: /

User-agent: *
Disallow:
```

Does this look alright?
I want to make sure I don't have the order messed up

The reason I want to disallow/ban them is because msnbot is indexing a bunch of files that don't, and have never, existed on our server. It's creating massive log files as a result.

Comment: There are robot.txt checkers on the Internet. Here is one http://www.frobee.com/robots-txt-check

Comment: This belongs on http://serverfault.com/ where server administration questions are answered. StackOverflow is for programming issues dealing with software development and code.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than blocking content access, return a 404 or a 410 when such URLs are probed. It will remove them from their index and bots will progressively stop searching for them (see https://youtu.be/G29Zt-UH_Ko).